# what happens if we multiply any given function in $H^p(\Omega)$ by a continuous periodic function ? Does the product stay in $H^p(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, sobolev-spaces

Let $f$ be a continuous $2\pi$ periodic function and $\Omega= [0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi]$. Now if $u\in H^p(\Omega)$, Sobolev space, then can we prove that $fu\in H^p(\Omega)$ ?

I know an equivalent statement available in 1 D in Linear integral equation by Rainer Kress which states

For a nonnegative integer $k$ let $f\in C_{2\pi}^k$ and assume that $0\leq p\leq k.$ Then for all $\varphi\in H^s[0,2\pi]$ the product $fg\in h^p[0,2\pi]$ and
$$ \Vert f\varphi \Vert_p \leq C\{ \Vert f \Vert_{\infty}+\Vert f^{(k)}\Vert_{\infty}\}\Vert \varphi\Vert_p $$

I would like to know does a similar result exists in $H^p(\Omega)$? Or any hint on proving it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If by continuous you mean smooth, then yes,

Comment: Thanks. Yes, we can assume smoothness. Could you please elaborate on how the inequality looks like and any idea about proof?

Comment: This is just the product rule if $f$ is $C^p(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Schraven, Thanks. Actually we cant assume $f$ to be enough smooth. I am trying to know the estimate as mentioned in the problem for $f$ say in $C^1(\Omega)$. If you know such a result please let me know.

Comment: @Bananach. What is galsey?

Comment: Sorry, let me try typing this again: If $f$ is only differentiable and $p>1$, then the result is false.

Comment: I am working on the proof (as it appears in my own research as a graduate student). A paper that uses this result is included [here, see Section 5](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~nicholls/papers/Final/dnoanal.prse.pdf) (D. Nicholls is my advisor). @Severin Schraven - I think this needs some justification with Sobolev norms to prove that really is the product rule. Corollary 8.8 in Linear Integral Equations by Kress requires justification by showing equivalence of norms (and is the first problem assigned at the end of the chapter).